# preg_match_all , get all img tag that include a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

this code get all img tags

```
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$a,$page);
```

but I want get tags that their filenames includes "next.gif" or "pre.gif"

for example :

```
$page = '
<img border="0" alt="icon" src="http://www.site.com/images/man.gif" width="90" height="90">
<img border="0" alt="icon" src="http://www.site.com/images/pre.gif" width="90" height="v">
<img border="0" alt="icon" src="http://www.site.com/images/2.gif">
<img border="0" alt="icon" src="http://www.site.com/images/next.gif" width="90" height="90">
';
```

and I output should be like this :

```
   <img border="0" alt="icon" src="http://www.site.com/images/pre.gif" width="90" height="90">
    <img border="0" alt="icon" src="http://www.site.com/images/next.gif" width="90" height="90">
```

Comment: Ooh I like this one. I'm gonna try something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have to go with this one:

```
/(<img[^>]*src=".*?(?:pre\.gif|next\.gif)"[^>]*>)/i
```

Or in PHP:

```
$regexp = '/(<img[^>]*src=".*?(?:pre\.gif|next\.gif)"[^>]*>)/i';
$iResults = preg_match_all($regexp, $str, $aMatches);
print_r($aMatches); // you'll see what you need
```

-- edit:
Oops. I made a mistake. The `.` in `pre.gif` and `next.gif` in the regexp the regexp must be escaped!! I didn't before.
-- edit

PS. You might be using preg_match_all wrong. The arguments are: (`pattern`, `subject`, `&matches`)

PS. The results of my pattern +  your subject:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <img border="0" alt="icon" src="http://www.site.com/images/pre.gif" width="90" height="v">
            [1] => <img border="0" alt="icon" src="http://www.site.com/images/next.gif" width="90" height="90">
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => <img border="0" alt="icon" src="http://www.site.com/images/pre.gif" width="90" height="v">
            [1] => <img border="0" alt="icon" src="http://www.site.com/images/next.gif" width="90" height="90">
        )
)
```